# Trim double quotation mark(") from a string

Tags: swift, trim, character-trimming

I have a string and I need to delete following characters

> \ " { ] }

from a string. Everything working fine except the double quotation mark.

My string is :

> {"fileId":1902,"x":38,"y":97}

after the following operations are performed:

```
let charsToBeDeleted = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\"{]}")
let trimmedStr = str.trimmingCharacters(in: charsToBeDeleted)
print(trimmedStr)
```

prints:

> fileId":1902,"x":38,"y":97

It trimmed first double quotation mark but not the other ones. How can I trim this string without double quotation marks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`trimmingCharacters(in` is the wrong API. It removes characters from the beginning (`{"`) and end (`}`) of a string but not from within.

What you can do is using `replacingOccurrences(of` with Regular Expression option.

```
let trimmedStr = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\"{\\]}]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

`[]` is the regex equivalent of `CharacterSet`.
The backslashes are necessary to escape the double quote and treat the closing bracket as literal.

---

But don't *trim*. This is a JSON string. Deserialize it to a dictionary

```
let str = """
{"fileId":1902,"x":38,"y":97}
"""

do {
    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8)) as! [String:Int]
    print(dictionary)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or even to a struct

```
struct File : Decodable {
    let fileId, x, y : Int
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(File.self, from: Data(str.utf8))
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Oops, my simultaneous edit crushed your changes. Sorry for that @vadian

Comment: @LinusGeffarth No problem, there is a rollback function.

Comment: Definitely the best approach

Answer (score 2):

I haven't test this but it would be something like this:

You may have to check if the escape of characters for `\` and `"` inside the set is used correctly.

```
let charsToDelete:Set<Character> = ["\\", "\"", "{", "]", "}"]
str.removeAll(where: { charsToDelete.contains($0)})
print(str)
```

Comment: `removeAll(where:)` is a mutating function so your code would only print `()`. I've fixed it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @LinusGeffarth